Does Reinforced Typings support exporting to a type declaration instead of an interface?
I need to export some C# types into TypeScript, I am using ReinforcedTypings for that, but I'd like to export my types as type Foo = { bar: number } rather than interface Foo { bar: number }. Is this currently possible?
On an unrelated note, I've cloned the repo but can't seem to compile it locally. It says the file "Reinforced.snk" is not found.
